# Async function in typescript not correctly running

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

A bit confused as to where I'm going wrong with this code. Basically, the console is outputting the correct `this.allNominations`, but doesn't seem to be running through the third for-loop at all. Thus the `nominationDepartmentMap` values aren't being populated at all. I know the question is a bit vague but any help would be appreciated!

```js
async getAllNominations() {
    this.loadingAllNominations = true;

    for (let nominee of this.allNominees) {
      this.apiService.getNominations(nominee.email).subscribe((data) => {
        this.allNominations.push(...data);
      });
    }

    console.log( this.allNominations);

    let nominationDepartmentMap = new Map<number, Nomination[]>();
    for (let department of this.departments) {
      nominationDepartmentMap.set(department.id, []);
    }

    for (let nomination of this.allNominations) {
      console.log('hello')
      for (let department of this.departments) {
        if (nomination.nominee.departmentId == department.id) {
          if (!nominationDepartmentMap.has(department.id)) {
            nominationDepartmentMap.set(department.id, []);
          }
          nominationDepartmentMap.get(department.id)!.push(nomination);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    console.log(nominationDepartmentMap);
}
```

[Picture of console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK7Y7.png)

Comment: "*the console is outputting the correct this.allNominations,*" [Is Chrome’s JavaScript console lazy about evaluating objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440)

Comment: You should put **all code** under the subscribe function to be sure "this.allNominations" has value. (the subscribe only make a call, not wait to completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait the the observables in the first for, you can try this:

```
async getAllNominations() {
        this.loadingAllNominations = true;

for (let nominee of this.allNominees) {
  this.allNominations.push(await this.apiService.getNominations(nominee.email).toPromise());
}

console.log( this.allNominations);

let nominationDepartmentMap = new Map<number, Nomination[]>();
for (let department of this.departments) {
  nominationDepartmentMap.set(department.id, []);
}

for (let nomination of this.allNominations) {
  console.log('hello')
  for (let department of this.departments) {
    if (nomination.nominee.departmentId == department.id) {
      if (!nominationDepartmentMap.has(department.id)) {
        nominationDepartmentMap.set(department.id, []);
      }
      nominationDepartmentMap.get(department.id)!.push(nomination);
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(nominationDepartmentMap);
}
```

or you can try with the `forkJoin` operator to wait for all observables.